# Strange date formatting needing to be put into proper format Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, datetime, format

I have data with a dates column that follows a MMYY format.

Ie: **1119** would be **November 2019** and **1211** would be **December 2011** and **110** would be **January 2010**....etc....

Not only that but there are **years** in the same column that need to be taken as **December** of whatever year it is.

Ie: **2011** is **December 2011**....etc....

Furtheremore, there are dates that make zero sense what so ever!

Ie: **1616** which would be..... Janfebrune 2016???

Those need to be ignored completely (unless someone understands this format but I just don't get it!)

A snippet of this data looks like this:

```
Year  Month  State  Contract   Exp Date
2010  1      OH     S          2017
2010  2      OH     C          1119
2010  1      AK     S          1234
2010  2      AK     S          1616
```

What could I do to change these strange dates to `datetime` formats?

Answer (score 0):

What i would do is use some regex to collect all your data and some ifs here and there to check it + your interpretation of that Exp_date (which i'm not totally sure about..., this may just be a simple exercise that requires you to extract data with a specific format)

```
import re

def split_exp_date( date):
    if len(date) > 4:
        return None
    month = int( date[:2])
    year = int( '20' + date[2:])
    if not 0 < month < 13:
        return None

    return month, year

test  = """
Year  Month  State  Contract   Exp Date
2010  1      OH     S          2017
2010  2      OH     C          1119
2010  1      AK     S          1234
2010  2      AK     S          1616
"""

r = re.compile( r'\n(?P<Year>[\d]+) +(?P<Month>[\d]{1,2}) +(?P<State>[\w]+) +(?P<Contract>[\w]+) +(?P<Exp_Date>[\d]+)')

res = r.finditer( test)

for e in res:
    print( e.groupdict())
    split_exp_date( e['Exp_Date'])
    Year = e['Year']
    Month = e['Month']
    State = e['State']
    Contract = e['Contract']
    Exp_Date = split_exp_date( e['Exp_Date'])

    print( Exp_Date)

#{'Year': '2010', 'Month': '1', 'State': 'OH', 'Contract': 'S', 'Exp_Date': '2017'}
#None
#{'Year': '2010', 'Month': '2', 'State': 'OH', 'Contract': 'C', 'Exp_Date': '1119'}
#(11, 2019)
#{'Year': '2010', 'Month': '1', 'State': 'AK', 'Contract': 'S', 'Exp_Date': '1234'}
#(12, 2034)
#{'Year': '2010', 'Month': '2', 'State': 'AK', 'Contract': 'S', 'Exp_Date': '1616'}
#None
```

This should give you your data in a much more accessible form that you can use/format hower you want

Comment: Getting an error when calling the dataframe `df = split_exp_date(data)
` and the error being `TypeError: utf_8_encode() argument 1 must be str, not bytes`

Comment: It looks like you are working with something different than a text file/string. Is it a dataframe from pandas? <br> I guess you could then just take the string from the array using indexes and then pass it to the function (maybe .decode() it if it is in binary format), but I'm not 100% sure since I've never personally used them and only reading the documentation